# Why cant I see my children class when defining `__init_subclass__` in my parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

So I am trying to implement the usage of python3.8's `__init_subclass__`.

Project directory structure:

```
project_folder/
    __init__.py
    base_class.py
    child_classes/
        child_class.py
```

In my `base_class.py` I have a class with a constructor snipped as follows:

```
class BaseClass(ABC):
    """Base for classes"""

    _registry: Dict[str, Type['BaseClass']] = {}

    def __init__(self,
                 child_property_name: str):
        """Initialize base"""
        self.child_property_name = child_property_name

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        """Initialize inheritors of this base class and add them to registry"""
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if inspect.isabstract(cls):
            return

        cls._registry[cls.child_property_name] = cls
    

    # -----------------------------------
    # Rest of the code here
```

And in my subsequent inheritor children class, I have a simple signature something like this:

```
class ChildClass(BaseEventHandler):
    """Child class"""
    
    # -----------------------------------
    # Rest of the code here
```

From what I understand, the information of the child class should be available to the BaseClass's `cls._registry`. The funny thing that's happening is, if I have all my child class in one single file in a folder structure as follows, everything works perfectly:

```
project_folder/
    __init__.py
    base_class.py
    child_classes.py
```

Not sure what's happening?

Comment: The subclass code has to *run* for it to work, so presumably, `child_class.py` isn't being imported anywhere in the first case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga aha! Yep, importing it properly worked! Thank you very much!